# is it possible to skip depth level in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

I recently started doing typescript and I was curious about skipping level depth,
is it possible to skip depth level in typescript?

```
// from
A -> B -> C

// to
A -> C
```

---

```
const sample = {
    A: {
        B: {
            C: "one",
        }
    },
};

type Make<A, Z> = {
    [B in keyof A]: {
        [C in keyof A[B]]: {
            [D in keyof A[B][C]]: Z;
        }
    };
};

function foo<T>(object: T): Make<T, number> {
    return object as any;
}

// outputs: one
console.log(foo(sample).A.B.C);
```

what if we want to **skip one level** like this?

```
// expected output: one
console.log(foo(sample).A.C);
```

I tried to do this but it didn't work

```
type Make2<A, Z> = {
    [B in keyof A]: {
        [D in keyof A[B][]]: Z;
    };
};

function foo2<T>(object: T): Make2<T, number> {
    return object as any;
}

// doesnt work
console.log(foo2(sample).A.C);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Typescript types will never affect run-time behavior; that's one of the goals of Typescript. If you want to remove an object, then you have to write the logic as code, not types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply skip the middle layer by using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) and conditional typing.

We iterate over the values of the object with the remapping accessor in `[K in keyof T]`, checking if its children `T[K]` are objects, if so, we return the inferred child of the `T[K]`, `Item`, otherwise we just return `T[K]`

```js
type SkipFirstDepth<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Record<string, infer Item> ? Item : T[K];
};

type Make = SkipFirstDepth<typeof sample>
```

Then it's typing will be

```js
{
    A: {
        C: string;
    };
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to skip every other layer all the way down you'll have to use recursive types.

```
type SkipEveryOtherDepth<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Record<string, infer Item>
    ? Item extends Record<string, any>
      ? SkipEveryOtherDepth<Item>
      : Item
    : T[K];
};

type Example = SkipEveryOtherDepth<{
  foo: {
    bar: {
      foo: {
        bar: {
          foo: 'bar';
        };
      };
    };
  };
}>;
```

Then the final type will be

```js
{
    foo: {
        foo: {
            foo: 'bar';
        };
    };
}
```

I did this off the cuff, so it may not work in every object shape but definetly works in these given examples.

[Check these examples in action at the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCGBbADgGwKYwLwwN4CgYiYBBALj0OOoCEKDrHiBhCgInHTYBoqmBfPjH69+Abnz4oAT2SYAygGsAlsgBiygE7QAIumRQAFgB4AKjHQAPKOjAATCDABK6UJrvHom5WADm3GHgwaQA+EOxKIgBtAGkYHxhFdGkQADMYUwBdClNYzItrWwdnVxB3TyhvPwCfVPRNGABJG0RwgH4mlpgcvIlxSRk5GABZeCSIpVUNbSg9AxNB9DS4JDR0EIHZBRVkAFEAN3rpAHkjermjMwKbe0cXNw8vH39A4LCIhhhY+LBE5OWsj0YvkrDdivcyo9Ks8amA6g1muhWkIOojENcindSuUntVXqEhEQOpM9odNCczpoLiY0RsmBQ0UIgZk+hIpFsYLtLKsMBMdgcjqdDOd9JdPqkQCB6EIAEbwTTSpgSqWRJgwOUK1VqmDKigAcg1eok2v6AmNxFNwj6ITEQA)

Comment: thank you for taking the time and answering the question!